# .htaccess returns 404 error while clean url

Tags: php, url, blogs

I am looking for a help, i am rewriting clean php url, i want my `main_blog.php?post_slug="something"` like `/Something`!

here is the code i have written but when i try to add it on localhost it works fine but not with the live server

```
RewriteEngine on             
# Rewrite for blog post  title=Title-Goes-Here

RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ main_blog.php?post_slug=$1 [NC,L]
```

The following is the `.htaccess` code, i would like to know why this shows 404 error ?

I am looking forward for help

Comment: Maybe .htaccess is not used? Try to put nonsense in it and see if you get an error. If not, google for 'enabling .htaccess'

Comment: Contact your hosting company first. There could be many different reasons. Maybe they're using some other web server than Apache or not have mod_rewrite enabled as default or they could have some other way to enable it/make rewrites.

Comment: there are other files in root folder .htaccess is working there!

Comment: I have created a blog folder inside that i have added htaccess

Comment: In that case I think main_blog.php is not in the same directory. Maybe a different path? You can try using a full URL to main_blog.php to see if that is the problem

Comment: working but it redirects me to main_blog.php?post_slug="somethig", either i trigger /something it rewrites url as mentioned

Comment: Wait, you are typing in url www.yoursite.com/something, and then you see in your url that 'real' version 'www.yoursite.com/main_blog.php?post_slug=something' ? That is strange. It *should* serve that real page instead and not change the url. I am confused too now.

Comment: yes if i add www.example.com/blog/test it redirects to www.example.com/blog/main_blog.php?post_slug='somethig'